# Removing \\\ from Saved Data

Tags: theme-options

I am saving some text to a setting field for use in an email template.

So the text that is being put into the textarea to save looks like this...

```
<p>some text <a href="http://www.website.com">[HERE]</a></p>
```

and after saving it looks like this....

```
<p>some text <a href=\\\"http://www.website.com\\\">[HERE]</a></p>
```

So what do I need to do to make it remove the `\\\` when I need to work with this data?

---

**UPDATE**

I am saving the option/setting with this...

```
update_option('contact_record_client_template', $post_client_template);
```

So when I retrieve it with

```
$client_template = get_option('contact_record_client_template');
```

I just need to remove the `///`'s

If I run `stripslashes()` on it, it removes 2 of the 3 `/`'s so it still leaves 1.

I also tried using `str_replace( '///', '', $value );` but it just seems to add more or do nothing

Comment: "I am saving some text to a setting field for use in an email template." how are you saving it? Where are you saving it? Without that information, it's really hard to give you any sort of answer.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy I updated my post with example, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `"` signs to `&quot;` automatically using PHP's [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) prior to your `update_option()` call:

```
$post_client_template = htmlspecialchars( $post_client_template );
update_option( 'contact_record_client_template', $post_client_template);
```

If you need to change `'` characters as well, use this:

```
$post_client_template = htmlspecialchars( $post_client_template, ENT_QUOTES );
update_option( 'contact_record_client_template', $post_client_template);
```